# rename .html file from <title> tag with python

Tags: python, html, regex

I have many html files saved to my computer.they have same  tags like this: `Rpi-Cam-Web-Interface- Page 2 - forum`
and the page number changes
I want to rename file to page number
I use this code:

```
import re
import os
pattern=re.compile('<title>RPi Cam Web Interface - Page \d*')
for i in os.listdir():
   parser=open(i,'r',encoding='utf-8')
   m=pattern.search(parser.read())
   parser.close()
   os.rename(i,m.group()[35:]+'html')
```

any better way?

Comment: Did it work? What are you unhappy with?

Comment: My code works fine. but I think maybe my code is beginner and there is a better way to do it.

Comment: And If I'm wrong, many webpages will be corrupted.(more than 250)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Spacing** For reasonably professional Python code (or for any Python code you or others may have to look at later - ideally, all code you ever write), it would be a good idea to follow the standard [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide, to improve readability. To start with, it recommends putting spaces between arguments and operators, and using 4 spaces for indentation:

```
pattern = re.compile('<title>RPi Cam Web Interface - Page \d*')
for i in os.listdir():
    parser = open(i, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    m = pattern.search(parser.read())
    parser.close()
    os.rename(i, m.group()[35:] + 'html')
```

**Raw string** It's a good idea to use raw strings when creating Python patterns so that [escape sequences aren't interpreted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix), and instead the backslashes are treated as *regular characters* inside the pattern. For this *particular* pattern you're using, it happens to not be necessary, but if you ever had to change it and match a newline `\n` or a word boundary `\b` etc, not having used a raw string would result in the script not running as expected.

In other words, you'd want to do something like:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'<title>RPi Cam Web Interface - Page \d*')
#                    ^
```

**Pattern** I see 2 issues with the pattern:

- The page number is *optional* because you're matching with `\d*` instead of `\d+`. Using `\d+` to match *one or more digits* would make the intent of the pattern clearer. (`\d*` matches "zero or more digits")
- You're manually extracting the page number from the match with `m.group()[35:]`. Use a capturing group in the pattern instead of having to manually count up indicies:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'<title>RPi Cam Web Interface - Page( \d+)')
#                                                         ^^^^^^
# ...
    page_number = m.group(1)
```

Comment: thanks it works. but why it would be better if I use raw string? Doesn't raw strings mean that escaping characters are interpreted as regular characters? well ,don't '\d' should be interpreted as escape character?

Comment: `\d` is not an escape character in a normal non-raw string, but many other characters *are* escape characters, like `\r`, `\n`, `\b`, and so on. To use *those* escape characters, you'll either have to double-escape the backslash in order to use them, or use a raw string. Simply using a raw string every time so you don't have to worry about it is the better choice.